# How to get get string with http session in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, signalr

I'm making a chat application in web api ASP-NET with C# in VS Code. The user registration and login is working with database. I added the SignalR sample code in to the Welcome page, but i want to modify: the User name need to be the logged username, and after when i click to ''Send Message'', need to look like this: ''acc1 says hello world''.

[SCREENSHOT ABOUT MY PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGbH3.png)

[image]
The ''Send Message'' button function is in the ''chat.js'' file, and i don't know, how can i get the ''username" string there. The `HttpContext.Session.GetString("username")` is not working in javascript.

**chat.js**

```js
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

//Disable send button until connection is established
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;



connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Wilcome.cshtml**

```html
@page
@model probagetrequest.Pages.WilcomeModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Wilcome</title>
</head>
<body>

    Welcome @HttpContext.Session.GetString("username")
    <br>
    <br>
    <a asp-page="index" asp-page-handler="logout">Logout</a>
    <a asp-page="profile">Change Profile</a>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">User</div>
            <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="userInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">Message</div>
            <div class="col-4"><input type="text" id="messageInput" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <ul id="messagesList"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**ChatHub.cs**

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"user={user}, message={message}");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `var user = '@HttpContext.Session.GetString("username")';` and use user object as your want.

If your script in separate file, you can set as `window` object and use in your js file.

`window.user = '@HttpContext.Session.GetString("username")';`

```
<script>
   var user = '@HttpContext.Session.GetString("username")'; //or window.user
   console.log(user)
</script>
```